# Someone who doesn't learn from the mistakes he made

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, pejorative-language

Is there a word or phrase that means someone who doesn't learn from his mistakes or makes the same mistakes again? It can be a noun or adjective or anything that implies the meaning.

Comment: can be a noun or adjective or anything that implies the meaning.

Comment: [Related](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/4732/word-for-disrespecting-eldest-half-sister-by-referring-to-her-husband-as-girly-g#comment16076_4732).

Comment: I'd just fix this if I had enough rep, and I don't want to bother the review queue with a single-character edit: 'neans'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the criminal justice world, they are known as **[repeat offenders](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/repeat-offender)**.  There is no reason that phrase could not be utilized (a bit poetically) to other spheres.

A similar term is **[recidivist](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/recidivist)**

> Denoting a person who repeatedly reoffends

A common quote, often misattributed to Einstein, is

> *Insanity is repeating the same mistakes and expecting different results.*

It likely was first used in publications by [Narcotics Anonymous](http://www.quoteyard.com/insanity-is-repeating-the-same-mistakes-and-expecting-different-results/).

Answer (score 5):

All people make mistakes.  Most people make mistakes repeatedly.  Some people make the same mistake very frequently before they learn.  I would call them **slow learners.**

Comment: "I would call them slow learners." So would Thomas Pynchon. (-:

Comment: .............explain the reference.............

Comment: http://www.pynchon.pomona.edu/slowlearner/

Answer (score 2):

*fool* - someone who knows better but doesn't do better

*stupid* - someone slow to learn a better way of doing something

Comment: Welcome to ELU, @chicgeekmama! Your word choices are actually good, but your answer would be better if you added some references and links to support your choice. Take a look around at some of the best answers, and follow their example.